# Custom content type appears with an empty option in the admin "add type of page" page in mezzanine

Tags: django, mezzanine

I am doing a small blog in Mezzanine for learning purpose and wanted to add a custom content type by sub-classing "mezzanine.pages.models.Page" and registering this model with admin. My classes look something like this:

*models.py:*

```
from django.db import models
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page

class Student(Page):
    dob = models.DateField("Date of birth")
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=30)
    gender = models.CharField("Gender", max_length = 5, choices=(('M','Male'),           
                                              ('F','Female')), default = 'M')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Students')

class Project(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey("Student")
    project_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="StudentProjects")
```

*admin.py:*

```
from copy import deepcopy
from django.contrib import admin
from mezzanine.pages.admin import PageAdmin
from .models import Student, Project

student_extra_fieldsets = ((None, {"fields": ("dob","name","gender","image")}),)

class ProjectInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Project

class StudentAdmin(PageAdmin):
    inlines = (ProjectInline,)
    fieldsets = deepcopy(PageAdmin.fieldsets) + student_extra_fieldsets

admin.site.register(Student, StudentAdmin)
```

Now, when I visit "http://localhost:8000/admin/pages/page/" to add my newly registered content type, I get an empty option with no name, but when I select I get the Custom Content type "Student" Page to add and edit.

Since I have just started with Django and Mezzanine, I cannot simply figure it out.

I am using "**sqlite**" as backend and not using "**South**"

Any pointers to this??

Thanx for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I removed that "***name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=30)***" in models.py and replaced it with:

```
first_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=30)
last_name = models.CharField("Last Name", max_length=30)
```

And now every thing seems OK!!. (Only if I used "**South**"